# Objective-C block doesn't return and call it self in the block?

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning to develop iOS applications and now I'm reading some Objective-C source code.

This is a method to get user profile.

```
+ (void)getProfile:(void (^)(NSString *message))completion {
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"module":@"profile"};
    [[self defaultManager] POST:KBaseUrl parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([self jsonOKForResponseObject:responseObject] && [self checkLogin:responseObject]) {
            [ProfileManager sharedInstance].rank = responseObject[@"Variables"][@"space"][@"group"][@"grouptitle"];
            [ProfileManager sharedInstance].credit = responseObject[@"Variables"][@"space"][@"credits"];
            [ProfileManager sharedInstance].gender = responseObject[@"Variables"][@"space"][@"gender"];
            completion(nil);
        } else {
            completion(@"fail");
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completion(@"fail");
    }];
}
```

My question is about the `completion` block.

I suppose that the `completion` block returns `void` and receives an `NSString` parameter.

In the block, **what does `completion(nil)` mean?**

Does that mean the block `completion` calls it self and send `nil` as parameter?

Doesn't that conflict with the parameter's type `NSString*`?

I'm not quite familiar with `block` in ObjC. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: yes you are right. It calls itself and sends nil as a parameter and it doesn't conflict with the NSString parameter. You are just passing nil to the NSString param.

Comment: FYI - all of your calls to `completion(xxx)` need to be changed to: `if (completion) completion(xxx);`. This is incase the call of `getProfile:` passes `nil` to the `completion` parameter.

Comment: why should we use if(completion) ? What harm could it cause if we pass nil as param without using if condition ?@rmaddy

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Try it. It won't be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. It calls itself and sends `nil` as a parameter and it doesn't conflict with the `NSString` parameter. You are just passing `nil` to the `NSString` param.

You can call the above method like:

```
[YourClass getProfile:^(NSString *message) {

       //message will be nill if you pass completion(nil);
}];
```

So when you pass the nill in the completion block, the message in the above method call will be nil!

The completion block is to notify you that your method call is complete, and at this point you can let that method pass certain paramteres , and if we consider your method:

```
+ (void)getProfile:(void (^)(NSString *message))completion {
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"module":@"profile"};
    [[self defaultManager] POST:KBaseUrl parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([self jsonOKForResponseObject:responseObject] && [self checkLogin:responseObject]) {
           .....
            completion(@"hey sucess");
        } else {
            completion(@"if loop failed");
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completion(@"some error occured");
    }];
}
```

and when you call the method getProfile:

```
[YourClass getProfile:^(NSString *message) {

       //Execution will reach here when the method call for getPRofile is complete and you have a result which you just sent through the completion block as a parameter which is a string  and is waiting for you to process.

      //you can do more from here
         if([message isEqualToString:@"hey success"]){
                //do something
         }

          if([message isEqualToString:@"if loop failed"]){
                //do something
         }
         if([message isEqualToString:@"some error occured"]){
                //do something
         }
}];
```

As per @rmaddy comment, iis always a good practice to use BOOL to indicate the status success or fail rather than depending on a string as string can get localized/changed. We shold use the string to get more description of the error.
So your block should be:

```
+ (void)getProfile:(void (^)(BOOL status,NSString *message))completion {

      .....
      completion(YES,@"hey success");

}
```

and you can call it like":

```
[YourClass getProfile:^(BOOL status, NSString *message) {

        if(status){
               //get the success message 
         }else{
              //get the fail message
        }

    }];
```

Comment: I think I had a misunderstanding before. I think that `NSDictionary *dic = ...}];}` is the body of method `getProfile:` and I thought that it was the body of block `completion`. After gone through your answer, I've come up with another question: shouldn't the block `completion` have a body? Where is the block's body? I think the block would not know what it should do without a body?

Comment: blocks can be used in many forms. They can be used as property, localvariable, as a param in method. When you use block as a parameter in a method, its body will be in the method where you call it. In my answer, the block body will be in the [YourClass getProfile:^(NSString *message) { //body starts frm here @penguin-penpen

Comment: you are calling another method with block in the getProfile method. That is not considered as the completion block body. [[self defaultManager] POST:KBaseUrl parameter .....is another method with failure block!

Comment: Finally get to understand. I simply considered block to be a piece of code to execute. Still have a lot to learn about block!

Comment: yeah, better late than never! You will face blocks everyday in your coding! For more understanding ofblocks http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks

Comment: This is a really poor design for the completion block. Don't just pass an `NSString` parameter with no other information to indicate success or failure. Basing success or failure on the value of a string isn't a good design. Strings can get localized or simply change over time. The string should just be extra information. Return a `BOOL` to indicate success/failure.

Comment: I agree with your comment and updated my answer accordingly :) @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your suggestion. As I'm new to ios development, I didn't realize that at all. I'll update my own code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Blocks had a lot of type like :-
As a local variable:

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
    As a property:

@property (nonatomic, copy, nullability) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);
```

As a method parameter:

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^nullability)(parameterTypes))blockName;
```

As an argument to a method call:

```
[someObject someMethodThatTakesABlock:^returnType (parameters) {...}];
```

As a typedef:

```
typedef returnType (^TypeName)(parameterTypes);
TypeName blockName = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

read more about it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Completion block does not return anything. It is just a piece of code to be executed, thats all. Though, you can give it some input where you call it so you can use the result elsewhere.

NSString *message is the input for your block so when you call your function getProfile as:

[MyClass getProfile:^(NSString *message) {

// write code to be executed when getProfile function finishes its job and   sends message here.
    }];

[MyClass getProfile:nil];

When used like this you're preferring not to do anything when getProfile finishes its job.

You are probably mixing your network manager's function's completion block with the one you wrote.